# C#: Building a object-based layout/grid using objects (Path)

Tags: c#, breadth-first-search

I am trying to figure out how to create a single object that can be used as a layout (meaning I can iterate through and find object in the layout). There will be two types of objects (square & connector). Each object has a reference to itself by use of the ID field and their directions.

Basically starting from the root object I can find the other objects from it by going through the hierarchy.

Example:

```
root = square1
root.Right = connector1
root.Right.Right = square2
root.Right.Right.Right = connector2
root.Right.Right.Right.Right = square3

root.Right.Left = square1
root.Right.Right.Left = connector1
```

The way I see it is that each objects alternate direction (left => right, above => below..) would be the next/previous item in the grid layout.

I thought about more of a BFS algorithm; the method I have so far obviously is not right and nowhere near BFS, but I am not sure if I am even on the right path to do this.

Can someone point me in the right direction by providing some feedback on possible solutions or point me to a similar question so I can solve this problem?

[image: Layout]

```
        public void Main()
        {
            LayoutObject connector1 = new LayoutObject(){ID = 1, TYPE="Connector", Left = square1, Right = square2, Above = null, Below = null};
            LayoutObject connector2 = new LayoutObject(){ID = 2, TYPE="Connector", Left = square2, Right = square3, Above = null, Below = null};

            LayoutObject square1 = new LayoutObject(){ID = 1, TYPE="Square", Left = null, Right = connector1, Above = null, Below = null};
            LayoutObject square2 = new LayoutObject(){ID = 2, TYPE="Square", Left = connector1, Right = connector2, Above = null, Below = null};
            LayoutObject square3 = new LayoutObject(){ID = 3, TYPE="Square", Left = connector2, Right = null, Above = null, Below = null};
            
            List<LayoutObject> objects = new List<LayoutObject>();
            objects.Add(square1);
            objects.Add(square2);
            objects.Add(square3);
            objects.Add(connector1);
            objects.Add(connector2);

            //This sets the first square in the layout
            LayoutObject root = new LayoutObject();
            root.Right = square1.Right;
            root.Left = square1.Left;
            root.Above = square1.Above;
            root.Below = square1.Below;
            
            root = BuildLayout(root, objects);
        )

        private LayoutObject BuildLayout(LayoutObject root, List<LayoutObject> objects)
        {
            if (root == null) return null;
            foreach (var neighbor in root.GetNeighbors())
            {
                if (neighbor == null) continue;
                if (root.Left != null && neighbor.Right != null && root.Left.ID == neighbor.Right.ID) root.Left.Left = neighbor.Right;
                if (root.Right != null && neighbor.Left != null && root.Right.ID == neighbor.Left.ID) root.Right.Right = neighbor.Left;
                if (root.Above != null && neighbor.Below != null && root.Above.ID == neighbor.Below.ID) root.Above.Above = neighbor.Below;
                if (root.Below != null && neighbor.Above != null && root.Below.ID == neighbor.Above.ID) root.Below.Below = neighbor.Above;
                BuildLayout(root.Left.Left, objects);
                BuildLayout(root.Right.Right, objects);
                BuildLayout(root.Above.Above, objects);
                BuildLayout(root.Below.Below, objects);
            };
        }
```

```
    public class LayoutObject
    {
        public string TYPE { get; set; }
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public LayoutObject Parent { get; set; }
        public LayoutObject Left { get; set; }
        public LayoutObject Right { get; set; }
        public LayoutObject Above { get; set; }
        public LayoutObject Below { get; set; }

        public List<LayoutObject> GetNeighbors()
        {
            return new List<LayoutObject>() { Left, Right, Below, Above };
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The key is calculating bounding rectangle for each element. Once you do that, you can simply draw without worrying about its contents or parents.

If you are just looking for a solution, you should do it in two passes:

DFS to calculate the size of each node.
Pseudocode is as follows:

Pass 1:
Node parent
Node RN,LN,TN,BN
visit(node)
visit(RN),visit(LN),visit(TN),visit(BN)
Top = min(RN.Top,LN.Top,TN.Top,BN.Top)
// similarly calculate the dimension and coordinates for the parent window.

Pass 2:
Draw each node in the BFS order:
paint(node)
paint(RN), paint(LN) , paint(TN), paint (BN).

Note that with this method you can have as many nodes as possible in a parent node, not just four.

Of course, you can optimize all this by using stacks instead of recursion, painting immediately after calculation instead of doing it in the second pass etc. But that depends on the exact framework you are using.